# How to see the content-type of a response in Nginx log file

Tags: nginx, log-files

Is it possible to see the `content-type` of a response to a request in `Nginx`'s log file? At the moment, this is what I see for the request in question:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2012:10:17:19 -0500] "GET /fonts/cantarell-bold-webfont.eot? HTTP/1.1" 200 22679 "https://www.example.com/blah/doc" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C)"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [official `nginx` documentation](http://nginx.org/r/log_format), you can use `$sent_http_content_type` in your `log_format` statement :

```
log_format myCustomFormatTemplate '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
    '"$request" $status $sent_http_content_type $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```